# NodeJS - Return a single status code from an async function using Array.protoype.map() to save multiple files in different locations in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3

I am a little stumped on how to handle this the best way possible. I've decided to rewrite this controller, and I need to (at least I think) make use of `promise.all()` here.

**Premise:**

In this application, the Admin user must be able to bulk upload a bunch of .pdf's at once that are for multiple users. The .pdf's adhere to a specific naming convention that my backend upload controller by using a `regEx`, pulls out a first and last name. These .pdf's are auto-generated in a program, that always names them exactly the same, so there is no human error in misspelling names.

Each call to the database and an AWS S3 Bucket is made within an `Array.prototype.map()` a function that is looping through and uploading a file to an S3 bucket, and then it takes the `Key` name of the file returned from `s3.upload()` and saves that `Key` to a user model in Mongo DB as a reference to their file(s) within the S3 Bucket.

**Example Code:**

This is what I currently have (that does work somewhat). This is the block of code responsible for what I described above. `employeeFiles` is created further up in the controller and contains an array of objects that each have a `file` and `id` property. The file name destructuring and user matching happen further up in the controller as well, and the `employeeFiles` array is a result of that. The `id` property contains the `mongo _id` of the employee, and the `file` property contains the file to be saved. This all works perfectly, and I don't think that code is needed for context here. `fileType` is a variable available within the scope of the controller:

```
const employeeFileUploadToDb = () => {

  employeeFiles.map((employee, i) => {
    const { file, id } = employee;
    const params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Body: file.buffer,
      Key: `${filetype}/${file.originalname}`
    };
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      }

      if (data) {
        //Save reference to Employee model
        let dataObj = {
          key: data.key,
          fileName: file.originalname,
          date: Date.now()
        };

        Employee.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: id },
          { $push: { [`${filetype}`]: dataObj } }
        )
          .then(resp => res.send(200))
          .catch(err => next(err));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I am making use of `next()` to handle any errors within the `s3.upload()` and `findOneAndUpdate()` functions (I do realize `findOneAndUpdate()` is deprecated) moving forward. My idea here is that if there is an error with one of the functions, `next()` will send it to my error handler middleware and keep going, versus ending the process and halting all of it.

Inside of every iteration of `s3.upload()`, I make a call to my database so that I can save the reference to the file uploaded to the `S3 Bucket`. Inside of a `then()` method of `Employee.findOneAndUpdate()`, I return a `(200)` response to let my client know everything has been uploaded to S3 and saved in my DB. So on each iteration of this `map()` function, I am returning a 200. If I have 10 files, I am returning 200 10 times.

I feel that I can convert this into an `async` function, and make use of a `promise.all()` to return a single status code upon completion. Returning that many status codes seem a bit crazy to me. But I am not too sure how to approach this while using a `map()` function to loop and make an async call on every iteration.

Hope this makes sense, and thank you in advance for looking at this!

Comment: What is meant to happen if one image fails.?   What I would do is make the upload into a promise, push into an array, and then `promise.all`, and then return success.

Comment: I feel your pain.  One thing to consider though, is does it really make sense to be calling `next` on each failed `Promise`, given that the results are coming back in an undefined order?  Is that something higher-level code can deal with?  Maybe you should just build up an array of `Promises`, wait for completion with `Promise.all`, and then you have a sane state to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I would split it up into a 2-step process. Upload in bulk and then save to mongo if it all worked out.

```
const employeeFileUploadToDb = () => {

  const uploadFiles = files => files.map((employee, i) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //...
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
     })
    });
  });


  Promise.all(uploadData(employeeFiles)).then((err, data) => {
     // Handle saving to mongo
  })
};
```